# I'm having collision detection issues

Tags: html, canvas, collision-detection, collision

Im working with html for the first time, though mygamepiece stops at the ground, it passes through the sides and top of the canvas. does anyone know how to fix this? Here is the code i'm using.

```html
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
    canvas {
        border:10px solid skyblue;
        background-color: powderblue;
     
     
     
    
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="startGame()">
    <script>
    
    
    var myGamePiece;
    
    
    function startGame() {
        myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "purple", 80, 75);
        myGameArea.start();
    }
    
    
    var myGameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function() {
            this.canvas.width = 1550;
            this.canvas.height = 745;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
            window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
                myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
                myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
            })
            window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
                myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");            
            })
        }, 
        clear : function(){
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        }
    }
    
    
    function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;    
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;    
        this.gravity = 0.1;
        this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        this.bounce = 0.5;
        this.update = function() {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
        this.newPos = function() {
            this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
            this.hitBottom();
        }
        this.hitBottom = function() {
            var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
            if (this.y > rockbottom) {
                this.y = rockbottom;
                this.gravitySpeed = -(this.gravitySpeed * this.bounce);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    function updateGameArea() {
        myGameArea.clear();
     myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
        myGamePiece.speedY = 0;    
        if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.speedX = -2; }
        if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.speedX = 2; }
        if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speedY = -3; }
        if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speedY = 4; }
        myGamePiece.newPos();
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
    
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hopefully this will give you a good idea of what i'm working with, hoping anyone will be able to give some advise.

Comment: I see no code that would prevent it from going beyond the upper and side bounds of the canvas.

Comment: If you run it and hold the left key it will slide past the left boundary wall of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way you prevent the box from exiting the bottom of the screen, you can alter the `x` and `speedX` values accordingly to prevent going off the left and right of the screen.

**Check left and right boundaries**

```
// hit left
if (this.x < 0) {
  this.x = 0;
  this.speedX = 0;
}

// hit right
var right = myGameArea.canvas.width - this.width;
  if (this.x > right) {
    this.x = right;
    this.speedX = 0;
}
```

If `x` is less than `0`, we reset it to `0` and reset the `speedX` to `0`. Same logic for the right hand side. If `x` is greater than the canvas width minus the characters width, set `x` to that and set the `speedX` to `0`.

**Here is a working snippet:**

```js
var myGamePiece;


function startGame() {
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "purple", 80, 75);
  myGameArea.start();
}


var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 300;
    this.canvas.height = 200;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
      myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}


function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.gravity = 0.1;
  this.gravitySpeed = 0;
  this.bounce = 0.5;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
  this.newPos = function() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
    this.hitBottom();
    
    // hit left
    if (this.x < 0) {
      this.x = 0;
      this.speedX = 0;
    }
    
     // hit right
    var right = myGameArea.canvas.width - this.width;
    if (this.x > right) {
      this.x = right;
      this.speedX = 0;
    }
  }
  this.hitBottom = function() {
    var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
    if (this.y > rockbottom) {
      this.y = rockbottom;
      this.gravitySpeed = -(this.gravitySpeed * this.bounce);
    }
  }
}


function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
  myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -2;
  }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 2;
  }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -3;
  }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 4;
  }
  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 10px solid skyblue;
      background-color: powderblue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
</body>

</html>
```

For the top wall you'll want to check if the `y` is less than `0` and then alter the `y` and `speedY` accordingly.